# Take Screenshot of Object Details

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visualforce-component, quickaction, salesforce-classic

I'm looking to create a button in salesforce (lightning and classic)  that I can add to any layout.  Clicking this button will take a screenshot of the details page and will then send you to a different page.  The screenshot will be taken using a javascript library, such as html2canvas.

What feature of salesforce should I be taking a closer look at to accomplish this?  I'm looking at Lightning Actions, Quick Actions, etc etc and getting overwhelmed.

Comment: I'm curious whether there's a better way of going about this. What's the use case?  Why screenshots?

Comment: I want a way to mark records for review, the screenshot was going to be used to annotate what was wrong with the record

Answer (score 1):

Lightning's Locker Service will prohibit you from rendering an entire html2canvas (or any other library) implementation. While this is a great security feature, it also means that what you want can't be done in Lightning. All you can do is open a compatible page (Visualforce, most likely), and have that render your screenshot from html2canvas (or a similar library). Basically, all you really need is a custom button that can open a Visualforce page, and add it to a page layout, then you should be able to render the screenshots as you wish.

Comment: when you say render, do you mean take?  Could I redirect to a visual force page that places the details page in an iframe, then use html2canvas to take a screenshot of the  inside of the iframe?

Comment: @Will You're prevented from exploring the DOM, you can still get parts of the page, but it'd be incomplete. You don't need an iframe (and I think it'd be sandboxed, anyways), but html2canvas allows to you specify which element you want to start rendering from, so you'd just put a span around an apex:pageBlock or apex:detail, etc, then you can render the entire thing using the standard page layout.